# Why is iterating over a vector so slow?

Tags: c++

I'm doing [Project Euler #7](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7), where you calculate the 10,001st prime. I've written a simple function to check if an integer is a prime number:

```
bool isPrime(int p)
{
    if (p % 2 == 0 || p <= 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i=3; i<=(int)sqrt((double)p)+1; i+=2)
    {
        if (p % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then in the main program I start at 2 and iterate through all subsequent odd numbers, counting each prime:

```
int count(1);
int i(1);
while (count != 10001)
{
    i += 2;
    if (isPrime(i))
    {
        count++;
    }
}

std::cout << "Answer: " << i << std::endl;
```

I then thought that I could improve on this function by keeping track of all the primes found so far, and feeding them into my `isPrime` function, like so:

```
bool isPrime(int p, std::vector<int> primes)
{
    if (p <= 1) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=primes.begin(); it!=primes.end(); it++)
    {
        if (p % *it == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (*it > (int)sqrt((double)p)+1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And the main program is changed to:

```
int count(1);
int i(1);
std::vector<int> primes(1,2);
while (count != 10001)
{
    i += 2;
    if (isPrime(i, primes))
    {
        count++;
        primes.push_back(i);
    }
}

std::cout << "Answer: " << primes.back() << std::endl;
```

The first version of my code gets the answer in less than a second, whereas the second takes over a minute. I don't understand why this is, surely the second version should be faster as `isPrime` is iterating over a smaller range of numbers? If anyone can offer any advice, thanks.

Comment: have you tried running things through a profiler and have you made sure you have enabled compiler optimizations?

Comment: you are running >10001! times, also isPrime makes copy of primes every time.

Comment: `primes` should at least probably be passed as a const reference to `isPrime` to avoid a copy of the vector to be made for every prime test.

Comment: Your prime function fails for `2`, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

You should change the signature of `isPrime()` to

```
bool isPrime(int p, const std::vector<int>& primes)
```

to avoid copying `primes` every time you call the function.